# which package should i use for that code given below

Tags: miktex

```
V_{i_{k}} = X_{i_{k}}+\Phi_{i_{k}}\times (X_{i_k}-X_{j_k})
```

This is not working in LaTeX. Which additional package should be used?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please also give us the text of the error message.

Comment: I'm almost sure that it is not working because you are missing math mode delimiters: `$......$`.

Answer (score 5):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

I don't think you need to load *any* supplemental packages to compile the following code; observe that the math material is set in inline-math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$V_{i_{k}} = X_{i_{k}}+\Phi_{i_{k}}\times (X_{i_k}-X_{j_k})$ 
\end{document}
```